# Unable to connect to the remote server when selecting IpEndPoint

Tags: c#, httpwebrequest, ip, webrequest

I've got c# code running on a computer with multiple IP addresses, and I've got following code to select an IP address for a httpWebRequest:

```
class Interact
{
    <data, cookies, etc>

    HttpWebRequest CreateWebRequest(...)
    {
        .....

            request.ServicePoint.BindIPEndPointDelegate = delegate(
            ServicePoint servicePoint,
            IPEndPoint remoteEndPoint,
            int retryCount)
                      {
                          if (lastIpEndpoint!=null)
                          {
                              return lastIpEndpoint;
                          }
                          var candidates =
                              GetAddresses(remoteEndPoint.AddressFamily);
                          if (candidates==null||candidates.Count()==0)
                          {
                              throw new NotImplementedException();
                          }

                          return
                              lastIpEndpoint = new IPEndPoint(candidates[rnd.Next(candidates.Count())],0);
                      };
            };

        return request;
    } 
}
```

Here's the code of GetAddresses:

```
    static IPAddress[] GetAddresses(AddressFamily af)
    {
        System.Net.IPHostEntry _IPHostEntry = System.Net.Dns.GetHostEntry(System.Net.Dns.GetHostName());
        return (from i in _IPHostEntry.AddressList where i.AddressFamily == af select i).ToArray();
    }
```

This code is supposed to select a random IP from avaliable IP list, and than stick to it.

Instead, every time I send request with it, I'm getting following exception:

`Unable to connect to the remote server`

How do I make this work?

Answer (score 2):

It looks like you are setting the port number of the end point to zero in the line:

```
lastIpEndpoint = new IPEndPoint(candidates[rnd.Next(candidates.Count())],0);
```

Unless this gets changed later on, it is unlikely that you will be able to connect to an HTTP server on port 0.  You may be able to use the port contained in the `remoteEndPoint`, or perhaps you can hard code the port number if it is well known (eg, 80 for HTTP server running on default port).

```
lastIpEndpoint = new IPEndPoint(candidates[rnd.Next(candidates.Count())], remoteEndPoint.Port);
```

Comment: Actually, this doesn't quite work. I've tried the solution proposed, and I'm still getting "Unable to connect to the remote server ---> System.Net.Sockets.SocketException: The requested address is not valid in its context 173.194.39.68:80" (I'm testing this on google)

Comment: @ArsenZahray what did you use for the port number?  Did you hardcode 80, or did you use remoteEndPoint.Port?

Comment: @ArsenZahray That error usually means that the IP address is not one that belongs to the machine - which has me scratching my head at the moment, since you are using `Dns.GetHostName()`.

Comment: @ArsenZahray It may be that the DNS / hosts entries on the machine are out of date, which means that results from GetHostEntry may be invalid.  Can you run `ipconfig` at the command line on the server to verify the actual IP addresses of the host adapters on your machine.  If none of them are 173.194.39.68, then check to see if the hosts file is overriding things (%SystemRoot%\system32\drivers\etc\hosts).

Comment: Note: per the System.Net.IPEndPoint.IPEndPoint code comments, a Port of 0 allows it to choose any available port.  "    //   port:
    //     The port number associated with the address, or 0 to specify any available port.
    //     port is in host order."